# REACT.NATIVE__NPM_UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT] options.port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received 65536

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, react-native, npm

I'm trying to run a react native app but I'm getting **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning** error.
[image]

I have a mac, OS X El Capitan v10.11 and the node version is `v.12.19`.

If anyone has already encountered this problem, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with Stencil dev server and the cause was that the 'host' for my server was set as 'localhost' and it was unable to solve that "dns".
The reason was that it was not defined in the "hosts" file of the system (located at etc/hosts).

Adding the next line to the hosts file solved the problem:

*127.0.0.1 localhost*

Comment: Thanks ! It's exactly this, i also find this solution